# Expected function or variable Error in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Application.Calculate = xlManual'
```

I put this line in my code to make calculations in manual mode, but it shows "expected function or variable" Error. 
Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such enumerator value. You are also using the `Application` object incorrectly.

Use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` instead

Answer (score 1):

**xlCalculationManual**
Returns or sets a XlCalculation value that represents the calculation mode.

```
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821260.aspx)

Comment: + 1 Or use the value `Application.Calculation = -4135`